# send each sheet to each persons via outlook

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, office-automation

I have a master sheet and a code to split it into separate sheet based on reviewer names, now i need to send all the splitted sheet to each of the reviewers based on sheet names, example: sheet named raj must be sent to raj@gmail.com, sheet named ravi must be sent to ravi@gmail.com I managed to find a code to send a single sheet via mail, i need help to send all the sheets to respective persons via outlook.

Attaching the code to send a single sheet.

```
Sub EmailWithOutlook()
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oMail As Object
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim wSht As Worksheet
    Dim ShtName As String
    Dim CurrDate As String
CurrDate = format(Date, "MM-DD-YY")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Make a copy of the active worksheet
    ' and save it to a temporary file
    Sheets("raj").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook

    FileName = WB.Worksheets(1).Name & " " & CurrDate
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill "C:\Users\Desktop\workfiles\" & FileName
    On Error GoTo 0
    WB.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\Desktop\workfiles\" & FileName

    'Create and show the Outlook mail item
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)
    With oMail
        'Uncomment the line below to hard code a recipient
        .To = "raj@gmail.com"
        'Uncomment the line below to hard code a subject
        .Subject = "Subject Line"
        'Uncomment the lines below to hard code a body
        .body = "Hi Raj" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
          "Please find the attached file for work"
        .Attachments.Add WB.FullName
        .Display
    End With

    'Delete the temporary file
    'WB.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
    'Kill WB.FullName
    'WB.Close SaveChanges:=False

    'Restore screen updating and release Outlook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set oMail = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Any idea guys ?

Comment: 1. I would create a masterdata sheet where you store the mail addresses and the corresponding worksheets.
2. Then you should include a for loop and encapsulate the outlook mail creation. Within this for loop go through each mailaddress and assign it to a variable (e.g. sMailRecipient) and also assign the corresponding worksheet to a variable for the attachement.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all worksheets in the workbook in the following way to compose an email for each recipient individually:

```
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For i = 1 To WB.Sheets.Count 
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)
    With oMail
        .To = WB.Sheets(i).Name & "@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "Subject Line"
        'Uncomment the lines below to hard code a body
        .body = "Hi Raj" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
          "Please find the attached file for work"
        .Attachments.Add WB.FullName
        .Send
    End With
Next i
```

You can read more about that in the following articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)
- [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/)
- [How to create and show a new Outlook mail item programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/26/outlook-create-show-message-programmatically/)

Comment: SO is for developers and not for requesting ready-made solutions, that means you should be familiar with a programming language. So. I'd suggest starting from the [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office).